# How to traverse an ordered "network"?

Tags: python, networking, graph, sequence, traversal

I have an interesting python "network" challenge. Not sure what data construct to use and am hoping to learn something new from the experts!

The following is a snippet from an ordered table (see `SORT` column) with a `FROM NODE` and `TO NODE`. This table represents a hydrologic network (watershed sequencing) from upstream to downstream. `TO NODE = 0` indicates the bottom of the network.

Given there can be many branches, how does one traverse a network from any given `FROM NODE` to `TO NODE = 0` and store the list of nodes that are sequenced over?

For example, starting at:

```
HYBAS_ID (this is same as FROM NODE)= 2120523430
```

see `<----` about 2/3rd way down, the sequence of Nodes would include the following:

```
[2120523430, 2120523020, 2120523290, 2120523280,2120523270,2120020790, 0]
```

Table:

```
 SORT   FROM NODE   TO NODE
30534   2121173490  2120522070
30533   2120521930  2120521630
30532   2120522070  2120521630
30531   2120521620  2120522930
30530   2120521630  2120522930
30529   2121172200  2121173080
30528   2120522930  2120523360
30527   2120522940  2120523360
30526   2120519380  2120523170
30525   2120519520  2120523170
30524   2120523440  2120523350
30523   2120523360  2120523350
30522   2120525750  2120523430
30521   2120525490  2120523430
30520   2121173080  2120522820
30519   2120523430  2120523020 <------- if you start network here
30518   2120523350  2120523020
30517   2120522820  2120523290
30516   2120523020  2120523290 <------ the second node is here
30515   2120523170  2120523280
30514   2120523290  2120523280 <------ third node here
30513   2120523160  2120523270
30512   2120523280  2120523270 <------ fourth
30511   2120523150  2120020790
30510   2120523270  2120020790 <------ fifth
30509   2120020790  0          <------ End.
```

Would a dictionary and some kind of graph structure work to traverse this network? The code may be fed a list of thousands or millions of `FROM NODES` to calculate the routing so efficiency is important.

Comment: Store them all in a dict with the from value as key and the to value as dict, and the problem is easy. If that takes too much memory, you can store them in a disk-backed key-value store, and it's just as easy.

Comment: For future clarity, "HYBAS_ID" is identical to "FROM NODE" (mistakenly overlooked standardizing the naming convention but they're equivalent).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard way to do this is with an unordered dictionary representing a directed graph, and then to iterate through it. First you have to populate the dictionary (which let's say is a csv for the sake of argument), and then iterate through the values. so

```
my_graph = {}
with open("myfile.csv") as f:
    for l in f:
        split_lines = l.split(",")
        my_graph[int(split_lines[1])] = int(split_lines[2])

HYBAS_ID = 2120523430
current_hybas = my_graph[HYBAS_ID]
return_value = [HYBAS_ID]
while current_hybas != 0:
    return_value.append(current_hybas)
    current_hybas = my_graph[current_hybas]

print return_value
```

Should approximately get you what you want.